# Get the unique numbers from a range

Tags: xml, xslt

I wonder if it is possible to get the numbers within a range and print them into own elements.

Say I have an input with a lot of elements with a number in it, some of them containing a numberrange:

```
<root>
<ele>
    <no>1</no>
</ele>
<ele>
    <no>3</no>
</ele>
<ele>
    <no>4-11</no>
</ele>
<ele>
    <no>12</no>
</ele>
```

and I want to get this (shortened, up to 11, like in the input):

```
<root>
<ele>
    <no>1</no>
</ele>
<ele>
    <no>3</no>
</ele>
<ele>
    <no>4</no>
</ele>
<ele>
    <no>5</no>
</ele>
<ele>
    <no>6</no>
</ele>
```

So far I have come up with this XSLT:

```
 <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//no">
        <no>
            <xsl:if test="not(contains(.,'-'))"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="contains(.,'-')">
                <xsl:variable name="beforehiven">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,'-')"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="afterhiven">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,'-')"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="diff">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$afterhiven - $beforehiven"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:value-of select="$diff"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </no>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

First I adress the ones without a hiven and output them. And I know that between 4 and 11 are 6 numbers, so I have to create new `<ele>` and `<no>`elements and give them the value 7-1, create a new variable 6-1 for the next one and so on.

Is this possible with XSLT? If yes, how?

Thanks for your time!

---

edit:
I am using xslt version 2.0

the complete output should be:

```
<root>
<ele>
    <no>1</no>
</ele>
<ele>
    <no>3</no>
</ele>
<ele>
    <no>4</no>
</ele>
<ele>
    <no>5</no>
</ele>
<ele>
    <no>6</no>
</ele>
<ele>
    <no>7</no>
</ele>
<ele>
    <no>8</no>
</ele>
<ele>
    <no>9</no>
</ele>
<ele>
    <no>10</no>
</ele>
<ele>
    <no>11</no>
</ele>
<ele>
    <no>12</no>
</ele>
```

Comment: _so I have to create new <ele> and <no>elements and give them the value 7-1, create a new variable 6-1 for the next one and so on_ Can you please explain this statement. What are the value `7-1` and variable `6-1`? Or is it that you just want to create elements with values between 4 and 11?

Comment: Can you please mention the XSLT version you are using, and the complete expected output for the shown input XML.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant 7-1 as 7 minus 1, giving back the value 6. My thinking was: the difference between 4-11 is 7, but since I already have 4 and 11 I need 7 minus 1, for the next element 6 minus 1, and so on. To answer in short: Yes, I want to create for each value between 4 and 11 an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be quite simple with XSLT 2.0 Try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ele[contains(no, '-')]">
    <xsl:variable name="from" select="substring-before(no, '-')" />
    <xsl:variable name="to" select="substring-after(no, '-')"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="xs:integer($from) to xs:integer($to)">
        <ele>
            <no>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </no>
        </ele>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```